# Ask for confirmation in the same div by swapping its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-manipulation

I have the following html:

```
<div class="modify">
    <a href="#" class="change" id="1">Change</a><br>
    <a href="#" class="delete" id="1">Delete</a>
</div>
```

And an according jQuery:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){

    var parent_element = $(this).closest('li');
    var url_string = $(this).attr('id') + '/delete/';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url_string,
        success: function(response) {
        parent_element.fadeOut(600, function() {
                parent_element.remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now I want to ask the user for confirmation within `.modify`. The current contents `.change` and `.delete` should disappear and be swapped for something like:

> Are you sure?
>
> Yes
>   No

This is how it would look in general:

[image: Initial State]

If the user presses *Delete* the contents should change like this:

[image: State after Delete was pressed.]

As you might have figured, if the user chooses

- *Yes*, the `parent_element` should be deleted
- *No*, `.modify` should return back its original state

What would be the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: sth like `if( !userConfirms() ) { return; }` before you execute your deletion..?

Comment: The tricky part for me seems to be the swapping of the contents and wiring up the new links that are swapped in, aswell as swapping back the original state.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your post? Its not too clear what you're saying.

Comment: I added pictures to clarify my problem.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I modified my answer, and you can improve it with your layout / effects. Does it approach what you wish for?

Comment: As you can notice, a clear question makes the difference. Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my answer after your additional note.

[codepen live example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CAcqt)

What about..

HTML

```
<div class="modify askState">
  <div class="ask">
    <a href="#" class="change" id="1">Change</a><br>
    <a href="#" class="delete" id="1">Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div class="confirm">
    <span class="confirmDeleteText">Are you sure?</span><br/>
    <a href="#" class="confirm confirmYes">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" class="confirm confirmNo">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var askState = true, modifyElement = $(".modify");

$(".delete").click(function(){

  askConfirmation();    
});

function askConfirmation() {
  toggleState();
}

$(".confirmYes").click(function() {
  var parent_element = $(this).closest('li');
    var url_string = $(this).attr('id') + '/delete/';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url_string,
        success: function(response) {
        parent_element.fadeOut(600, function() {
                parent_element.remove();
            });
        }
    });
});


$(".confirmNo").click(function() {
  toggleState();
});

function toggleState() {
  if( askState ) {
    modifyElement.  addClass("confirmState").removeClass("askState");
  } else {
    modifyElement.removeClass("confirmState").  addClass("askState");
  }
  askState = !askState;
}
```

CSS

```
.confirmState .ask {
  display: none;
}

.askState .confirm {
 display: none;
}
```

I added HTML so that the original text wont get lost (if you do `innerHTML=newText` then you cannot restore its innerHTML properly without backing up).

Please also note that its fairly readable:

1. IF I click "delete", then ASK confirmation (semantic code).
2. IF I ask confirmation, then CHANGE State (functional code, could have been nice to make `toConfirmState()` in stead of `toggleState()`).
3. (then in new state)
   IF I click "confirmYes", then DO perform code (functional code, could have been nice to make a delete function (semantic code))

Comment: @j-dog I hope that you will also notice how I split functions in stead of putting everything directly inside eachother (to achieve more readability and reusability). You can further decide whether or not to change `toggle()` to `toAskState()` and `toConfirmState()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".delete").click(function(){    
var ans = confirm("Are You Sure To Delete This Record...");

if(ans)
  {return true;}
else
  {return false;}

... ur code so on
}
```